# How to count the number of common nodes in Neo4j - query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have graph database (neo4j) with two nodes: **Person**, **Word**.
The **Person** node is in relation with **Word**, and for example two Person nodes can be combined with the same Word.

I would like to return count of Word nodes, which are with the relationship between two Persons (two persons have relationship with the same word).

For example I have the nodes `Person {name: 'Bart}'` and `Person {name: 'Jack'}`. I would like to count how many Word nodes have relationship with this two persons pic rel
[image: example graph database]

Comment: Just FYI, the suggested "duplicate" is not actually relevant for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the word(count)s for your `:Person` nodes

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WITH COLLECT(p) AS persons
UNWIND persons AS p1
UNWIND persons AS p2
WITH p1,p2
WHERE id(p1) > id(p2)


MATCH (p1)-[:WORD]->(w:Word)<-[:WORD]-(p2)
RETURN p1.name AS p1Name,
       p2.name AS p2Name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT w) AS sharedWordCount,
       COLLECT(DISTINCT w.string) AS sharedWords
```

Comment: Hi, did you try a similar query on a larger sets? The query looks like a n^2 complexity. How practical is it?